# What would be the most feasible roadmap for building a smart contract using Python?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, metamask, python, pyethereum

I have no knowledge of Solidity or Web and am a beginner. I have some knowledge(not vast, by any means) of Python. Please suggest a roadmap to learn the necessary tools and  where I can use Python for smart contracts developement and design, wallets in DeFi.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would advise you to look into Vyper https://vyper.readthedocs.io/en/stable/
It is a programing language for writing smart contracts that has Python syntax and is in general inspired by Python.

Comment: Thanks for helping me out! I will look into this!! Thanks again!